# Question regarding central limit theorem proof using Lyapunov's condition

Tags: probability-theory, convergence-divergence, central-limit-theorem

Let $X_n\sim \operatorname{independent} \operatorname{Uniform} (0,n^2)$. I need to find $a_n$ and $b_n$ such that $$\frac{\sum_{k=1}^n (X_k -a_n)}{b_n}$$ converges in distribution to a non-degenerate limit.

My apporach is to use **Lindeberg condition (Lyapunov's condition)**  to this and prove this converges to standard normal distribution.

This is my work so far:

$X_k= n^2 Z_k$ where $Z_k$ ~ $U[0,1]$ .

Under  Lyapounov's condition i use $\delta =2$ . So $$E|X_k|^{2+\delta} = E|X_k|^4 = n^8E|Z_k|^4.$$

$$D_n =\sum_1^n \sigma^n_k = \sum_1^n \frac {n^4}{12}.$$

Using Lyapounov's condition $$\frac{E|X_k|^{4}}{D^2_n} = \frac{E|X_k|^4\sum_n^8}{(\sum\frac {n^4}{12})^2}.$$

if my work is correct , then this seems to be a divergent series so this as a results of that lindeberg condition will not satisfy.

Can anyone help me figure out what did i do incorrectly ?

Maybe there is an easy way to prove this rather than this way.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think the Lyapunov condition is needed here. Try to verify the Lindeberg condition directly. Using your notation,

$$ D_n^2 = \sum\limits_{k=1}^n\frac{k^4}{12} = O(n^5) $$

Now, let $a_k = E[X_k] = \frac{k^2}{2}$. Then, $|X_k - a_k| \leq \frac{3}{2}k^2$. So,

$$ \begin{eqnarray} \frac{1}{D_n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nE[|X_k-a_k|^2\chi_{\{|X_k-a_k|>\epsilon D_n\}}]
&\leq& \frac{9}{4D_n^2}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^4P(|X_k-a_k|>\epsilon D_n)\\ 
&\leq& \frac{9}{48\epsilon^2D_n^4}\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk^8\end{eqnarray}$$

Since the sum behaves like $O(n^9)$ and the denominator behaves like $O(n^{10})$, the above quantity converges to $0$. So the Lindeberg condition holds.

Comment: I have a small question about how you got the last step from the step before that. I think you have used the Chebyshev Inequality isnt it . Since the $var(X_k)=n^4/12 $ , in the numerator it should be $k^8$ , instead of $ k^6$. isnt it ?

Comment: Yes my mistake. The argument still works though since the numerator will behave like $O(n^9)$.

Comment: Thank you.  I have another question in the denominator we have $D{4}_n$ which should be a $\sum K^8$ isnt it ? So how did you tell that denominator behave like $O(n^{10}) $ and numerator like $O(n^9) $ although the order of two summations are same  ? I am sorry i am not really good at analysis.

Comment: The asymptotic behaviour can be found from [Faulhaber’s formula](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Faulhaber%27s_formula). As an example, consider the special case, $\sum\limits_{k=1}^nk = n(n+1)/2$. Does this look familiar?

Comment: Hello @ Flowsnake my original question is to find a non-degenerate limit . So i want to know, if the question was to find the non-degenerate random variable, then is this still the correct answer or not. Thank you

Comment: Nondegenerate means non constant. So yes this answer is correct.

Comment: How did you conclude that since $a_k = E[X_k] = \frac{k^2}{2}$ then $|X_k - a_k| \leq \frac{3}{2}k^2$?

Comment: @НикитаВасильев Since $X_k \leq k^2$ the upper bound holds because of the triangle inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$\def\dto{\xrightarrow{\mathrm{d}}}$Your application of Lyapnov condition is indeed correct, but the resulting sequence is convergent. In fact, suppose $Z \sim U(0, 1)$ and for any $δ > 0$,$$
E(|X_k - E(X_k)|^{2 + δ}) = (k^2)^{2 + δ} E(|Z - E(Z)|^{2 + δ}) = c_1 k^{4 + 2δ}\\
\Longrightarrow \sum_{k = 1}^n E(|X_k - E(X_k)|^{2 + δ}) = c_1 \sum_{k = 1}^n k^{4 + 2δ} \sim c_2 n^{5 + 2δ}. \quad (n → ∞)
$$
Analogously,$$
s_n^2 = \sum_{k = 1}^n D(X_k) = \sum_{k = 1}^n \frac{k^4}{12} \sim c_3 n^5. \quad (n → ∞)
$$
Therefore,$$
\frac{1}{s_n^{2 + δ}} \sum_{k = 1}^n E(|X_k - E(X_k)|^{2 + δ}) \sim \frac{c_2 n^{5 + 2δ}}{(c_3 n^5)^{\frac{2 + δ}{2}}} = \frac{c_4}{n^{\frac{δ}{2}}} → 0, \quad (n → ∞)
$$
which by Lyaponov CLT implies$$
\frac{1}{s_n} \sum_{k = 1}^n (X_k - E(X_k)) \dto Y \sim N(0, 1).
$$

Comment: Thank you . Can you specify what are those $c_1 , .. c_4$ means ?

Comment: @Statlover All these are computable constants not depending on $n$.

Comment: Hello @ Alex my original question is to find a non-degenerate limit . So i want to know, if the question was to find the non-degenerate random variable, then is this still the correct answer or not. Thank you